# Subsequence if there exists increasing mapping?

Tags: real-analysis

A sequence $(b_n)$ is a subsequence of the sequence $(a_n)$ if there exists an increasing mapping $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $b_n= a_{f(n)}$.

Can someone explain the significance of having an increasing mapping? I don't see how my understanding of subsequences would change if that wasn't in the definition.

Thanks.

Comment: Without the "increasing", you would have $2,1,3,4,5,6,\dots$ as a subsequence of $1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$.

Comment: The concept the definition is trying to depict is to "keep" only certain terms, with their relative order in the original sequence. We ask for $f$ to be increasing to preserve the order of the terms we're selecting.

Comment: To avoid rearrangement.